# The Microsoft Access Database Engine does not recognize

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I use Access at work, I'm mostly self-taught and I know very little code .  I've built a data base for handling HR KPI´S. In some of my queries, since 2016 started (2015 still runs), several reports I run now pops the error:

> "The Microsoft Access Database Engine does not recognize 'C_Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.NOTRAB' as a valid field name or expression".

I'm not sure why the report would be giving me an error about it.
Query Code:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.MONTOO) AS SumaDeMONTOO
    SELECT  Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.EMPRESA,
            Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.CENCOS,
            Left([Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT]![AMES],4) AS Año,
            Right([Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT]![AMES],2) AS Mes,
            Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.CODIGO,
            Fecha_maxmes_Calendario.MáxDeFecha
    FROM Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT INNER JOIN Fecha_maxmes_Calendario
            ON Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.AMES=Fecha_maxmes_Calendario.Ames
    GROUP BY Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.EMPRESA,
            Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.CENCOS,
            Left([Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT]![AMES],4),
            Right([Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT]![AMES],2),
            Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.CODIGO,
            Fecha_maxmes_Calendario.MáxDeFecha
PIVOT Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT.COHADE;
```

Comment: There is not `C_Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT` in your code. are you sure this is the query that giving you error?

Comment: Sorry I posted it again

Answer (score 0):

As soon as this query doesn't contain `C_Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT`, it means that the problem is one of queries 'Hrs_Permiso_TI_NT' or `Fecha_maxmes_Calendario`. Try to open them and locate error